# What is the difference between dateModified, dateCreated and dateUpdated?

Tags: assets

Can someone explain exactly what each of the above refers to when talking about assets? In particular, the difference between dateModified and dateUpdated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` are pretty standard columns that you can find in pretty much every Craft database table. They store the date in which the row was created and last updated, respectively.

`dateModified` is an assets-specific thing, and that stores the time that the *file* was last modified, according to the file system.

Comment: Thanks. So dateUpdated is the attribute to order by if I want to produce a list of 'new' assets?

Comment: @BruceJohnson Probably `dateCreated`, since `dateUpdated` will get updated whenever you make changes on your asset’s metadata.

Comment: I should have mentioned it before but that's exactly the behaviour I'm looking for. I want the most "newly updated" assets, if you like.

Comment: In that case `dateUpdated` is the way to go!